# Getting peer dependency error react/react native

Tags: ios, react-native, cocoapods

npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: react-native@0.70.0
npm ERR! Found: react@18.2.0
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR!   peer react@">=16.3.0" from @callstack/react-theme-provider@3.0.8
npm ERR!   node_modules/@callstack/react-theme-provider
npm ERR!     @callstack/react-theme-provider@"^3.0.7" from react-native-paper@4.12.4
npm ERR!     node_modules/react-native-paper
npm ERR!       react-native-paper@"^4.12.4" from the root project
npm ERR!   peer react@"*" from @react-navigation/bottom-tabs@6.3.3
npm ERR!   node_modules/@react-navigation/bottom-tabs
npm ERR!     @react-navigation/bottom-tabs@"^6.3.3" from the root project
npm ERR!   23 more (@react-navigation/core, @react-navigation/drawer, ...)
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer react@"18.1.0" from react-native@0.70.0
npm ERR! node_modules/react-native
npm ERR!   peer react-native@"*" from @react-navigation/bottom-tabs@6.3.3
npm ERR!   node_modules/@react-navigation/bottom-tabs
npm ERR!     @react-navigation/bottom-tabs@"^6.3.3" from the root project
npm ERR!   peer react-native@"*" from @react-navigation/drawer@6.4.4
npm ERR!   node_modules/@react-navigation/drawer
npm ERR!     @react-navigation/drawer@"^6.4.4" from the root project
npm ERR!   15 more (@react-navigation/elements, ...)
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: react@18.1.0
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR!   peer react@"18.1.0" from react-native@0.70.0
npm ERR!   node_modules/react-native
npm ERR!     peer react-native@"*" from @react-navigation/bottom-tabs@6.3.3
npm ERR!     node_modules/@react-navigation/bottom-tabs
npm ERR!       @react-navigation/bottom-tabs@"^6.3.3" from the root project
npm ERR!     peer react-native@"*" from @react-navigation/drawer@6.4.4
npm ERR!     node_modules/@react-navigation/drawer
npm ERR!       @react-navigation/drawer@"^6.4.4" from the root project
npm ERR!     15 more (@react-navigation/elements, ...)
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.

System:
OS: macOS 12.6
CPU: (8) arm64 Apple M1
Memory: 103.00 MB / 8.00 GB
Shell: 5.8.1 - /bin/zsh
Binaries:
Node: 18.9.0 - /opt/homebrew/bin/node
Yarn: Not Found
npm: 8.19.1 - /opt/homebrew/bin/npm
Watchman: 2022.09.12.00 - /opt/homebrew/bin/watchman
Managers:
CocoaPods: 1.11.3 - /opt/homebrew/bin/pod
SDKs:
iOS SDK:
Platforms: DriverKit 21.4, iOS 16.0, macOS 12.3, tvOS 16.0, watchOS 9.0
Android SDK: Not Found
IDEs:
Android Studio: 2021.2 AI-212.5712.43.2112.8609683
Xcode: 14.0/14A309 - /usr/bin/xcodebuild
Languages:
Java: 11.0.12 - /usr/bin/javac
npmPackages:
@react-native-community/cli: Not Found
react: ^17.0.2 => 17.0.2
react-native: 0.68.2 => 0.68.2
react-native-macos: Not Found
npmGlobalPackages:
*react-native*: Not Found

Comment: Please try to give more details about:
- when you are getting the error, 
- what's your configuration (OS, framework, etc.)
- format the quoted code/output, 
It looks like a dumped, no-begin, no-end, garbage on this page. Good luck!

Comment: Kinda new here sorry for that, i've added my specifications. I can see that react native community cli , react native macos and react native global package is showing not available but inside vs terminal it shows that its issue with pods and that [!] The Podfile does not contain any dependencies.

[!] Automatically assigning platform `iOS` with version `11.0` on target `p3` because no platform was specified. Please specify a platform for this target in your Podfile. See `https://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podfile.html#platform`.

Answer (score 2):

Try to install it with this command npm install --legacy-peer-deps and than start your project again.